# Javascript - not loading

Tags: javascript, html

I got a strange bug actually that I cannot explain. In a PHP page, I have 2 div container on body and many javascript include like below :

```
<script src="js/md5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/diacritics.js"></script>
<script src="js/customBoard.js"></script>
<script src="js/orderTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But none are loaded. Even with Google Chrome Developer's Console, on "Elements", they aren't shown. On "Network", same. This case occurs in others browsers too.

Example of my code :

```
<body class="board">
    <div class="navBoard bg-custom2-primary">

    </div>

    <div class="boardContent">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/md5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/diacritics.js"></script>
    <script src="js/customBoard.js"></script>
    <script src="js/orderTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Show in DOM :

```
<body class="board">
    <div class="navBoard bg-custom2-primary">...</div>
    <div class="boardContent"></div>
</body>
```

If I put all the script on beginning of body, it works. But it worked on bottom before. I don't understand. If I put a "Test" after the div.boardContent, this one doesn't even appear.

It's not a cache problem. Even with CTRL+F5 & by disabling cache, it occur.

Any idea ?

**EDIT : Solution found.**

See code below :

```
<div id="b2_1" style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="content" cid="2" type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Contenu de la carte">
    <input id="externalReference" type="text" placeholder="(opt) Référence externe liée">
</div>
```

The textarea element, not closed, was grabbing all the remaning lines of my code for his value(), making the  tags to be inside of the textarea, making them not to load. After that, the browser fixed all HTMLElement not closed - that's why the Developer's Console didn't shown the  Elements.

Full code below requested :

```
<body class="board">
    <div class="navBoard bg-sc2-primary">
            <button class="btn btn-light"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"> SC-2 TeamBoard</button>

            <div class="selectTeam">
                    <select id="selectTeam" class="form-control">
                            <option selected><i>Sélectionnez un groupe</i></option>
                            <option>Groupe 1</option>
                            <option>Groupe 2</option>
                            <option>Groupe 3</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="boardContent">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0.5em;">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p075">
                                                    En attente
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="0" class="card-body p075" style="padding-bottom:0.25em;"><p class="bold center clear" style="padding-bottom:0.5em;">En attente de la sélection d'une équipe</p></div>
                                            <div id="b0" class="card-footer text-muted p075" style="display:none;">
                                                    <div id="b0_1" style="display:none;">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="b0_2" style="display:initial">
                                                            <button class="btn bg-sc2-secondary" style="width:100%;" onClick="createCard(0);">+</button>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0.5em;">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p075">
                                                    En cours
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="1" class="card-body p075" style="padding-bottom:0.25em;"><p class="bold center clear" style="padding-bottom:0.5em;">En attente de la sélection d'une équipe</p></div>
                                            <div id="b1" class="card-footer text-muted p075" style="display:none;">
                                                    <div id="b1_1" style="display:none;">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="b1_2" style="display:initial">
                                                            <button class="btn bg-sc2-secondary" style="width:100%;" onClick="createCard(1);">+</button>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:0;">
                                    <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p075">
                                                    Terminé
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="2" class="card-body p075" style="padding-bottom:0.25em;"><p class="bold center clear" style="padding-bottom:0.5em;">En attente de la sélection d'une équipe</p></div>
                                            <div id="b2" class="card-footer text-muted p075" style="display:none;">
                                                    <div id="b2_1" style="display:none;">
                                                            <textarea id="content" cid="2" type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Contenu de la carte">
                                                            <input id="externalReference" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(opt) Référence externe liée">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="b2_2" style="display:initial;">
                                                            <button class="btn bg-sc2-secondary" style="width:100%;" onClick="createCard(2);">+</button>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/md5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/diacritics.js"></script>
    <script src="js/customBoard.js"></script>
    <script src="js/orderTable.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: whtat your console says?

Comment: My console did not say anything. But I just got this solved. I'm not deleting the post because it could be important : Within a div, I've got another div with "display:none" style. On that other div, I got a textarea that I did not close with </textarea>, resulting, seems like, to apply the display none for the rest of my code, even outside of the div. Strange HTML reaction.

Comment: @P.Jerome answer it!

Comment: Not strange at all, browsers are allowed to handle invallid HTML as they wish, there's no standard for that. Some browsers are more clever than others when fixing HTML errors. How would a browser know what is purposed to be the content of the the textarea, if you're not closing the tag.

Comment: Please delete your post, because your post is not written with enough explanations.

Comment: You should use some Smart Code Editor that shows errors like not closed tags. When you are not closing tags or make a similar mistakes - unexpected things can happen.

Comment: please share project structure

Comment: Hi, if you think that your solution could be handy for someone other, you can answer your own question. In this way, the question won't be visible in the "unanswered questions" section of this website

Comment: @brk : Done. I've edit the initial post.

Comment: @Teemu : True. Actually I guess that everything after the textarea is considered by the browser inside of it as his value(), hiding every scripts called on bottom inside of this content. But that strange that, in that case, Google Chrome doesn't even close automatically the TEXTAREA, letting the body closing tag appear. If you take my code, with Google Chrome updated to date, you'll not notice any closing textarea tag.

Comment: @Mārcis P : Thanx for the advice.

Comment: @Cristian Traìna : Done, didn't noticed. Can only accept my own answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A textarea not closed was hiding all the scripts. See edited initial post for more informations.